# Decode 5-digit binary string back into character

Tags: javascript, swift, string, binary

I've created a simple function that is able to translate every alphabetic character (`a-z`) into a **`always 5-digit binary string (like "00000->a" or "11000->y")`**

**SWIFT**:

```
 let alphabeth_array=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
 for i in 0..<32 {
   let binary_code = String(i/16%2) + String(i/8%2) + String(i/4%2) + String(i/2%2) + String(i%2)
   print("\(alphabeth_array[i]) : \(binary_code)")
}
```

---

**JAVASCRIPT**:

```
 var alphabeth_array=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
 for (var i=0; i<32; i++) {
   var binary_code = (i/16%2).toString() + (i/8%2).toString() + (i/4%2).toString() + (i/2%2).toString() + (i%2).toString()
   console.log(alphabeth_array[i] + " : " + binary_code)
}
```

---

But now I'd like to decode the binary strings back into their connected characters from the `alphabeth_array` you can find above.

**SWIFT**:

```
let binary = "00000" //starting with the binary string
let character = getChar(binaryCode: binary)

func getChar(binaryCode: String) -> (String) {
   // programm logic
   return result
}
```

---

**JAVASCRIPT**:

```
var binary = "00000" //starting with the binary string
var character = getChar(binary)


function getChar(binary) {
   // programm logic
   return result
}
```

I have absolutely no clue how to reverse the decoding function to translate binary string back into the connected character. Any help would be very appreciated, thanks! *(I would prefer gettings just some small code snippets, Swift or javascript - which language does not matter
!)*

Comment: Dear dude who hit the dislike button! Would you be so kind and tell us what there could be improved?

Comment: If you prefer getting js results i would leave out the swift part...

Comment: And which answer will be the best? JS or SWIFT??

Comment: I would then still ask two questions, one for each language. The "best" answer is usually the fastest, shortest or best explained. Now how could you decide that?

Comment: I'm curious, whats your usecase for such a strange text encoding?

Comment: @Alexander `such a strange text encoding? ` - I'm sure the use of binary text encoding is not that "strange". Instead of using the default 8-bit pattern I prefer using a way smaller bit pattern (5-bit)

Comment: @Jonas0000 Well it is strange. It's lower case only, latin letters only, with no punctuation or internationalization. There's a reason why Unicode exists :p. It's also really strange to represent binary as a string of `0/1` characters is a strange choice, which makes takes up at least 1 byte per 1 bit (7 bits of unused overhead!) and makes it impossible to do constant-time indexing. It's really a job for `Data`.

Comment: @Jonas0000 If you're so concerned about making it smaller, start with using `Data` over `String`, and and use 1 bit per "payload bit" rather than using 8 bits to represent 1 "payload bit" as it currently is

Comment: It's not about making the bit itself smaller it's about making a message to transmit smaller (faster to transfer). "10001" is smaller then "10000000100101001"

Comment: @Jonas0000 How did you get `10000000100101001` from `10001`?

Comment: @Jonas0000 Take the string `"abc"` for example. The byte representation is: `01100001 01100010 01100011`. 3 bytes. After your "optimization", `"abc"` will become `"00000 00001 00010"` (spaces added for clarity). Those "bits" aren't bits, they're characters encoded as a byte each. The byte representation is `00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 00110000`... 15 bytes. Because you converted each original single byte character into 5 single byte characters, which just happen to be `'0'`, and `'1'`.

Comment: @Alxeander You didn‘t get it right? - It‘s not about the data size of the binary itself its only about the count of possibilities, about the length of the data where it doesnt matters if the data is a string or not ! (5bits or chars—>5possib  & 8bits or chars—>8possib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `init?<S>(_ text: S, radix: Int = default) where S : StringProtocol` initializer to convert your binary string into an integer and use it as the index to access your alphabet array element. You can also use `String(_ value:, radix:, uppercase:)`
 initializer to convert your array indices to binary:

```
let alphabeth = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
var bins: [String] = []
for index in alphabeth.indices {
    let binary = String(index, radix: 2)
    let zeros = repeatElement("0", count: 5 - binary.count).joined()
    bins.append("\(zeros)\(binary)")
    print(alphabeth[index], bins.last!)
}
for binary in bins {
    if let index = Int(binary, radix: 2) {
        print(alphabeth[index])
    }   
}
```

Comment: May I recommend our lord and saviour, `map`? https://gist.github.com/amomchilov/3315221827a7e41af9791d6c6ec75226

Comment: @Alexander kkk I like map as well but the question it is just how to convert a single binary into an integer. `Int(string, radix: 2)` I just tried to make it as simple as possible to show the logic.

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the string with radix `2`, add an offset of `10` and convert the value to a value with radix `36`.

```js
function getCharacter(string) {
    return (parseInt(string, 2) + 10).toString(36);
}

function getBinary(string) {
    return ('000000' + (parseInt(string, 36) - 10).toString(2)).slice(-5);
}

console.log(getCharacter('00000')); // a
console.log(getCharacter('11000')); // y
console.log(getBinary('a'));        // 00000
console.log(getBinary('y'));        // 11000
```

Answer (score 1):

As Leo says in the first sentence of [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48153918/1271826), one can convert that binary string to a character in Swift as follows:

```
let alphabetArray=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
let string = "00010"
let c = alphabetArray[Int(string, radix: 2)!]
```

Or you can bypass `alphabetArray` entirely with:

```
let c = Character(Unicode.Scalar(Int(string, radix: 2)! + 97)!)
```

Comment: I wonder why this answer which it is exactly the same as mine posted after mine gets two votes

Comment: You described what he could do, but you kind of buried the lead. (I must confess that it wasn't until I re-read your answer that I realized that my answer was implied by the narrative in the first sentence of your answer.) I just showed two very simple examples of how to do it. If it really bothers you, feel free to edit your answer to show example of your first approach and I can delete this if you really want. I didn't intend to steal your thunder, but just to show simple, practical examples of how to do it.

Comment: @Rob no worries

Comment: @LeoDabus - Lol, now I get down-votes for clarifying your answer.

Comment: @Rob I am already used to it. I only keep answering at SO to interact with people like you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const getChar = num => alphabeth_array[parseInt(num, 2)];
```

Comment: @jonas0000 yes. Thats what the function does.